# How to know the name of the fields of a list that is empty?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, splist

In a Sharepoint there is a SPList that I should check if a name of field exist. (If exist I add content, if not exist I do something else)

Now I'm doing that:

```
SPListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems();
SPFieldCollection spFieldCollection =listItems.Fields;
foreach (SPField field in spFieldCollection)
 {
     String name = field.Title;

     if (name == "nameField") {
         return true; // Exist
     }
 }
```

that works ok, except if the list is empty. How can I check if a name of the field exist before add content to the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check on the `Fields` property on the `SPList`:

```
SPFieldCollection fields = spList.Fields;
```

Use the method `ContainsField` to check if a field exists:

```
return spList.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName);
```

> **fieldName** 
>   Type: System.String A string
>   that contains either the display name
>   or the internal name of the field.

[SPFieldCollection.ContainsField Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfield.aspx)